# How do I get a subscribe Value from a Firestore Observable on the first attempt?

Tags: angular, firebase

Running the code below the this.usersList returns an observable with a value which is correct and can used in @ngFor etc..  But when I subscribe to the observable to use it other functions the first (res: any) Array shows up empty and then shows up complete after.  I have attached a photo of the logs.  Yes I can make this work but I would like to run it cleaner and not have that first empty res Array.

ts

```
  getData() {
    this.usersList = this.unitLogSevice.getUserList();
    console.log("usersList",this.usersList)
    this.usersList.subscribe((res: any) => { 
      console.log("res",res)
    });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: I think your having an asynchronous issue - meaning that here `console.log("usersList",this.usersList)` the userList is not populated yet. What is `this.unitLogSevice.getUserList();`? Can you update the question with more details and a bit more complete code?

Comment: @ThomasDegroot please share more detail in your question, if you give me a method without telling on which angular event hooks its being called, how can anyone find the solution, expect more detailed questions from you! Thanks!